# Подскажите, верна ли пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

Со школы придешь, математику сделаешь, и делай что хочешь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не верна. Начиная с грамматики.

"Придешь", "сделаешь" и "делай" - разные наклонения, значит, у нас две основы и нет причин их объединять - требуется запятая (или, что в данном случае точнее передаёт интонацию, тире).

*Из школы придешь, математику сделаешь — и делай что хочешь!*

Comment: Поддерживаю, что тире лучше, но запятая тоже корректна, неверной её нельзя назвать, просто здесь будет присоединение.

Comment: Галина, извините, не пойму логику ответа. Вы написали, что нет причин объединять основы, требуется запятая (тире). В исходном предложении у автора вопроса запятая ведь есть, и правок не было...

Comment: Саша Стрелец, у меня, увы, полно таких описок. Взгляд застрял на "со школы", а далее я изобразила предпочтительный знак. Причём и запятую отнюдь не клеймила позором и нехорошими словами.